# Can't set arguments in Eclipse to define Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I've downloaded Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu 14.10. I put them into my user folder. Eclipse in Eclipse folder and Tomcat 7 in Tomcat folder. When I try to register an argument in my Tomcat 7 server inside Eclipse, it doesn't write the argument.

If I do this in Windows, everything works fine.

So what should I do?

To register a variable I try this:

- Add a tomcat 7 server.
- Click in the tab **Servers** and click on <kbd>Open Launch Configuration</kbd>
- Enter a new **vm argument** and click <kbd>ok</kbd>.

But if I go back to this screen, the **vm argument** is not set.

---

Edit:

I found that my workspace didn't create my `.metadata` folder. But don't know why.

Comment: @Fabby Why would Eclipse Luna be off-topic? You're talking about it like it's an OS--but [Eclipse Luna is just an application](https://www.eclipse.org/luna/) which the OP is trying to run on Ubuntu. (See also [this wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Luna).) [We do help people run third-party applications on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). If the problem were due to a bug, it would probably be off-topic. But I don't think that's the case here. The best thing would probably be [for Diego Macario to post their solution as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First download the `tar` version from `Eclipse`.
Open terminal and type this command, `sudo tar -xvf eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt/`.

Above the parameter `-C` create a new archive.
So the files are being copied to the `/opt/` folder.

Now you need to create a file inside this `/usr/share/applications/`
folder with `eclipse.desktop` name.

With a editor put this configuration.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 4
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

Save and close the file